# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis using count with expression inside it

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
SELECT Hotel_Name, COUNT(H_CHECK.Hotel_checkIn >= 'JUL-1-2016' AND H_CHECK.Hotel_checkIn <= 'JUL-31-2016') FROM HOTEL, H_CHECK
GROUP BY Hotel_Name
```

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

I have tried putting Parenthesis in many ways, but I couldn't find the solution. I'm using Oracle Application Express 11G.

This is the query:

Display the hotel name that has more than 2 customers checked in on July 2016.

Comment: No JOIN condition, how come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you fix your immediate syntax problem, you need proper `JOIN` syntax.

One way to fix the problem is simply to move the conditions to a `WHERE` clause, resulting in a query like this:

```
SELECT Hotel_Name, COUNT(hc.hotel_id)
FROM HOTEL h LEFT JOIN
     H_CHECK hc
     ON h.hotel_id = hc.hotel_id  -- I don't know what the right join condition is
WHERE hc.Hotel_checkIn >= DATE '2016-07-01' AND
      hc.Hotel_checkIn <= DATE '2016-07-31'
GROUP BY Hotel_Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot `count` based on `condition` in `Select` statement of your sql query.

```
COUNT (
            H_CHECK.Hotel_checkIn >= 'JUL-1-2016'
        AND H_CHECK.Hotel_checkIn <= 'JUL-31-2016')
```

This is wrong.  You can do it like>

```
    SELECT Hotel_Name,
         COUNT (1)               
    FROM HOTEL
    join H_CHECK
    ON  H_CHECK.Hotel_checkIn >= 'JUL-1-2016'
    AND H_CHECK.Hotel_checkIn <= 'JUL-31-2016'
GROUP BY Hotel_Name
having count(1) > 2;
```

Comment: Oh... Thanks... Then I tried to put this after GROUP BY Hotel_Name:

HAVING COUNT(H_CHECK.Hotel_checkIn >= ‘30-JUN-2016’ AND H_CHECK.Hotel_checkIn <= ‘1-AUG-2016’) > 2

And I get ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis again

Comment: @XING You can absolutely do a conditional count!

Comment: @Boneist..I just follwed the best practices.. :-)

Comment: @XING `You cannot count based on condition` ... that's incorrect and has nothing to do with best (or worst) practices though. Whether it makes sense for the OP to do a conditional count in their query is a different matter, but it remains possible to do so.

Comment: @Boneist..Bt once you told that we must tell the east and best possible solution. I found that putting it as join is easy to understand and thats why suggested. Do you feel putting a conditional count is better or putting it as a join..Also when i said `You cannot count based on condition` i posted the sql and certainly with that sql you cannot count.

Comment: @XING I think we're probably talking at cross-purposes here. For sure, it's best to advise the OP to go with best practice (although sometimes what we think is best practice might actually not make sense for the OP as they know their system best). However, you said it wasn't possible to use conditions in a count, whereas it's entirely possible with the use of CASE (which is what the OP was missing). I think maybe you were trying to say to the OP that their code won't work with that syntax, but there's a better way of doing it? If so, that wasn't entirely clear (hence why I commented *{:-) )

Comment: :-)) My bad english ..huhhh

Comment: @XING In this OP's case, I'm not convinced they have the correct join conditions between the two tables, so that doesn't help us help them. Certainly, from what they've said, getting all the rows from the two tables and then doing a conditional count is likely to be less performant than your suggestion of only picking the rows which meet the condition before doing the count. Just to be clear: I wasn't disputing the query you suggested (although whether the join condition is right is anyone's guess based on the lack of info from the OP!) *{:-) I hope that's clarified my meaning?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `CASE ... END` from your conditions inside your count. You're after something like:

```
SELECT Hotel_Name,
       COUNT(case when H_CHECK.Hotel_checkIn >= 'JUL-1-2016'
                       AND H_CHECK.Hotel_checkIn <= 'JUL-31-2016'
                       then 1
             end)
FROM   HOTEL, H_CHECK
GROUP BY Hotel_Name;
```

However, there are a number of concerns I have regarding your query:

1. if your `hotel_checkin` column is of DATE datatype, then you should be comparing it to DATEs not strings. I.e. `H_CHECK.Hotel_checkIn >= to_date('07-01-2016', 'mm-dd-yyyy')` - this way, you avoid relying on implicit conversion of the string into a date, which relies on your NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter setting. This could be changed and may cause your query to fail.
2. `FROM   HOTEL, H_CHECK` Don't use the old-style method of joining; instead, use the ANSI style method: `FROM hotel cross join h_check`
3. Did you really mean the join to be a cross join or did you forget to add the join conditions?
4. You should alias the `hotel_name` column to aid maintainability.
5. You should also give your count column a name.
6. Since you're only counting rows with a checkin between 1st and 31st July 2016, you should move this condition into the where clause (as XING has shown in their answer) *unless* you need to also show hotels that don't have any checkins within that time period.
7. Your condition assumes that there are no time elements to the hotel_checkin column - ie. everything is set to midnight. If, however, you could have a date with a time, bear in mind that your count will ignore all rows with a checkin date of 31st July 2016 that are after midnight. In which case, your upper bound needs to change to: `H_CHECK.Hotel_checkIn < to_date('08-01-2016', 'mm-dd-yyyy')`

Comment: How do I make sure that it only display the Name for hotel with more than 2 customer between two dates?

Comment: @NasrulArif See Gordon Linoff's answer - all you'd need to do is then include a having clause along the lines of `having COUNT(hc.hotel_id) > 2`.

Comment: I see that works really well just like I need... Thanks